# How can I set up alarm in Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I plan to set up an alarm service in my Android app. My application doesn't even start. It stops at the  `val pendingIntent = ...` 
row. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

The function which sets up the alarm look like this:

```
private fun startAlarm() {
   val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
   val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
   val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
   val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10)
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
}
```

I have the receiver in the manifest file:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false" />
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
thank you in advance

Comment: The code looks good to me. What do you mean by **It stops**? Does the App crash (If yes, can you share the logcat error log)? What Android version are you using?

Comment: Yes. it crashes with an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.goalplan/com.example.goalplan.MainViewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.goalplan: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
How can I set the flag?

Comment: the solution:   val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    applicationContext,
    NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
    intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

Comment: Yes, starting from some Android version, the calling code can be a bit different. And your code should be working fine.

Comment: The onReceive() function of AlarmReceiver is not called. Why? What else shall I do?

Comment: Has the time passed when you run the code?

Comment: yes. The time has passed meanwhile. I tried testing in the emulator as well. I added a println line to the onReceive(). but nothing printed

Comment: If the time has passed, you can either wait for the next day, or you can change your time in code so that an immediate event can be triggered.